# Tensorflow Dataset.from_generator blocks input?

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow

I want to build a project that requests will be put to a python Queue at any arbitrary time, and a set of tensorflow models consume those requests from the queue, and return their results immediately.

The models are in different threads, different tf.Graph, but the structure and weight values are the same.

Every model use tf.data.Dataset.from_generator to encapsule a python iterator which fetch request from the queue.

The problem is, when there is more than one models, request might be blocked until future request come. From testing results, it seems the python iterator indeed got the request just at the time it was put in the queue, but no result came from the model. Moreover, there seems no request was discarded, but blocked by maybe the tf Dataset iterator.

Here is my test code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import sys
import random
import time

from queue import Queue
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

thread_count=int(sys.argv[1])
request_queue=Queue(128)

def data_iter():
    while True:
        yield request_queue.get()

def task():
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        ds=tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_iter, (tf.int32), output_shapes=([1, 8]))
        sample=ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            coord=tf.train.Coordinator()
            threads=tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
            while not coord.should_stop():
                try:
                    result=sess.run(sample)
                    print(result)
                except:
                    coord.request_stop()
            coord.join(threads)

executor=ThreadPoolExecutor(thread_count)
try:
    for i in range(thread_count):
        executor.submit(task)

    rand=random.Random()
    for i in range(100):
        request_queue.put(np.full((1, 8), i, 'int32'))
        time.sleep(1e-3)#to let the model get request from the request_queue
        t=rand.randint(5,10)
        print('round {}, request_queue size is about {}, sleeping {} secs...'.format(i, request_queue.qsize(), t))
        time.sleep(t)
finally:
    for i in range(thread_count):
        request_queue.put(None)
    executor.shutdown()
```

Environment: python 3.5.3, tensorflow 1.4.0

testing result:

1. Running with one model: `python tf_ds_test.py 1`

The result looks like:

```
round 0, request_queue size is about 1, sleeping 6 secs...
2017-12-21 10:42:24.924251: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
round 1, request_queue size is about 0, sleeping 6 secs...
[[2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]]
round 2, request_queue size is about 0, sleeping 5 secs...
[[3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]]
round 3, request_queue size is about 0, sleeping 7 secs...
[[4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]]
round 4, request_queue size is about 0, sleeping 6 secs...
[[5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5]]
round 5, request_queue size is about 0, sleeping 7 secs...
...
```

Everything goes well.

2. But when running with 32 models: `python tf_ds_test.py 32`

The result looks like:

```
2017-12-21 10:45:41.660251: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
round 0, request_queue size is about 1, sleeping 9 secs...
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
round 1, request_queue size is about 0, sleeping 5 secs...
round 2, request_queue size is about 0, sleeping 8 secs...
round 3, request_queue size is about 0, sleeping 10 secs...
[[4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]]
[[2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]]
[[3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]]
round 4, request_queue size is about 0, sleeping 8 secs...
round 5, request_queue size is about 0, sleeping 6 secs...
round 6, request_queue size is about 0, sleeping 10 secs...
[[6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6]]
[[5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5]]
round 7, request_queue size is about 0, sleeping 9 secs...
[[7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7]]
round 8, request_queue size is about 0, sleeping 5 secs...
round 9, request_queue size is about 0, sleeping 10 secs...
round 10, request_queue size is about 0, sleeping 6 secs...
round 11, request_queue size is about 0, sleeping 10 secs...
[[8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8]]
round 12, request_queue size is about 0, sleeping 8 secs...
```

The request blocked! The python iterator consumed the request immediately, but the model give no result until an arbitrary period maybe until the model got its next request.

Does anybody has any idea? How can I let those model return result immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Could you modify the loop that generates elements into the queue to:

```
for i in range(100):
    request_queue.put(np.full((1, 8), i, 'int32'))
    print('round {}, queue size {}'.format(i, request_queue.qsize()))
```

and share the output?

I tried reproducing your issue (using the nightly build of TF), but things ran smoothly even with 1000 tasks and 10000 iterations of the loop.

Could you also try this with the nightly build of TF?

Comment: I tried the nightly build of TF, the output didn't change, and I tried your modification of the loop with 32 tasks and 10k iterations, the output is like below:

`round 0, queue size 1
...
round 127, queue size 128
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
round 128, queue size 125
round 129, queue size 126
round 130, queue size 127
round 131, queue size 128
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
round 132, queue size 128
[[3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]]
...`

I add `time.sleep()` in the code just for checking whether the model outputs the result immediately after it get a data.

The problem shown in both win7 and CentOS 7.2.1511